# Create imageview dynamically

Tags: java, android, layout, picasso

I can't seem to get these image views working.  I wan't to create a few imageviews dynamically but I want them to have a template or so from xml.

My loop looks as so:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLinearLayout);

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){

        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);
        imgView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        imgView.setId(R.id.coverview1);
        layout.addView(imgView);
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://blah.com/image.jpg").into(imgView);

    }
```

I'm creating a few images and just placing some temporary image in them but can't seem change the image size at all.

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout">

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/coverview1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxWidth="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Taking the advice of the answer below, I added what he said but now am not able to change the scale type.

```
imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imgView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

But the image is still the height of the container and not stretching.

Comment: "can't seem change the image size at all" What you mean?

Comment: I mean that I want to set it so that it is not full width of device, something like 80% of device width and center it but I can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Need to add `LayoutParams` for your `ChildView` Like:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                yourCalculatedWidth, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

params.gravity=Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;

imgView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Is there a reason why I can not set any attributes? For example I setBackgroundColor and setScaleType are not doing anything.

Comment: You can set all attribute, What you have tried and what happened if you try.